# how to convert the partial derivatives to matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

> I need to find the partial derivatives to one nonlinear equation
>        x1^2+3x1x2-5x1^2-x2
>        and convert it to matrix. any help is high
>        appreciated. and the out put should be matrix coefficients thank you
>        in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got your question, you can get the partial diff of the equation like the following:

```
syms 'x1' 'x2';
mat = [diff(x1^2+3*x1*x2-5*x1^2-x2,x1);diff(x1^2+3*x1*x2-5*x1^2-x2,x2)];
```

Or using the gradient:

```
gradient(x1^2+3*x1*x2-5*x1^2-x2)
```

Comment: thank you a lot,but i need the coefficient matrix even the zero element must appear in it,also i need it for n variables,please help

Comment: my pleasure. you can add zeros in the `mat` matrix. Or if you want to place the gradient on a diagonal of a squared matrix likes `diag(gradient(x1^2+3*x1*x2-5*x1^2-x2))`.

Comment: ok,how to make that commands as a function in m file?and ask me to input my equation..pls help